# Ruby Regex How to specify not to match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How do you say not to match in Ruby Regex

ex. you do not want to return true if it sees 'error'

/\b(error)\b/i

I know this returns true when it sees error, how do you say 'not' in this case? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the proper Ruby operator:

```
/\b(error)\b/i !~ someText
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following excuse the /error/ pattern not sure exactly what you want to match here

```
return true unless b =~ /error/
```

or

```
return true if b !~ /error/
```